# Problem with geometry and wrapfig

Tags: geometry, wrapfigure

In the example below, I have a problem between the `geometry` setting and `wrapfig` and the `\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}` command.
When removing either the `\geometry{...}` or the `\setlength{...}` command, there is no problem.

EDIT : The problem occurs whith LaTeX but not with pdfLaTeX.

Near the question 3 a symbol ` is comming from somewhere ...

How to solve this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,centering,reversemarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %german,francais
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\geometry{top=1cm,left=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,footskip=.5cm}

\begin{document}


\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-1)(5,5)
Essai
\end{pspicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
Soit un segment [AB] de longueur 8 cm et le demi-cercle C de diamètre [AB], de centre O.
M est un point de demi-cercle C et H est le pied de la hauteur issue de M dans le triangle AOM.
On souhaite savoir où placer le point M pour que l'aire du triangle soit égale à 4.
\par\smallskip
On note $x=\rm AH$ et on appelle $f$ la fonction qui modélise l'aire de AOM.
\begin{enumerate}
\item A quel ensemble appartient la variable $x$ ?
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Exprimer $f(x)$ en fonction de AO et MH.
\item En utilisant le théorème de Pythagore montrer que ${\rm MH}^2=16-(4-x)^2$.
\item En déduire une expression de $f(x)$.
\end{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Montrer que le problème posé revient à résoudre ${\rm MH}^2=4$
\item Résoudre dans R l'équation $X^2=12$
\end{enumerate}
\item Résoudre le problème posé.
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image: My document]

Comment: This is a strange behavior.  If you leave the geometry package away, the backtick also disappears. I have no idea.

Comment: Remove `left=1.5cm,` and there and no backtick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
When removing `\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%` there is no backtick too ...
But this is not a solution for me :  how to set the left margin now ?
Is this this is a bug from "geometry" ?

Comment: The problem occurs with pdflatex too -- you only need a suitable sized graphic. E.g. I can get it with `\fbox{\rule{10cm}{5cm}`. Your wrapfig overlaps a list and depending on the exact place where the graphic ends you get unwanted side-effects -- that's why it works when you change the geometry. Adding e.g. `\par\medskip` before the problematic \item helps too.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now why I did'nt have this problem in the last years ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `\WFclear` at the end of the second `enumerate` seems to fix it.  I would still avoid using list environments which overlap `wrapfig` in any way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,centering,reversemarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %german,francais
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\geometry{top=1cm,left=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,footskip=.5cm}

\begin{document}


\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
\fbox{\begin{pspicture}(-5,-1)(5,5)
Essai
\end{pspicture}}
\end{wrapfigure}
Soit un segment [AB] de longueur 8 cm et le demi-cercle C de diamètre [AB], de centre O.
M est un point de demi-cercle C et H est le pied de la hauteur issue de M dans le triangle AOM.
On souhaite savoir où placer le point M pour que l'aire du triangle soit égale à 4.
\par\smallskip
On note $x=\rm AH$ et on appelle $f$ la fonction qui modélise l'aire de AOM.
\begin{enumerate}
\item A quel ensemble appartient la variable $x$ ?
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Exprimer $f(x)$ en fonction de AO et MH.
\item En utilisant le théorème de Pythagore montrer que ${\rm MH}^2=16-(4-x)^2$.
\item En déduire une expression de $f(x)$.
\end{enumerate}\WFclear
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Montrer que le problème posé revient à résoudre ${\rm MH}^2=4$
\item Résoudre dans R l'équation $X^2=12$
\end{enumerate}
\item Résoudre le problème posé.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I use wrapfig and enulmerate for a long time and I never had this strange bug.
It occurs with LaTeX (and XeLaTeX) but not with pdfLaTeX.
And as said before, not when "left=1.5cm" is removed in geometry. It's amazing !
Is this a known bug ???

Comment: The konwn problem with wrapfig and enumerate or itemize is when the wrafigure is putted **inside** the enumerate.
But here it is **outside**.

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\WF@fudgeparshape` should be corrected: it misses `\parshape` after `\WF@finale`:

```
\def\WF@fudgeparshape{\relax \ifnum\c@WF@wrappedlines<\tw@ \WF@finale
        \parshape   %%% <<<<< Missed in the original
  \else \afterassignment\WF@fudgeparshapee \fam \fi}
```

P.S.  Well, `\WF@finale` is also buggy — but it is a different story!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will this update be integrated in the package update ?

Comment: I’m afraid to ask…  The date of 2003 on the package tells a lot…  Is Donald active now?

Comment: This problem and another T.SE report of Delta appearing in `\intertext` are the same problem. I tracked down the missing `\parshape` (for the Delta problem). Why didn't anyone report the bug? Even with just a link to here. Thanks @IlyaZakharevich for tracking the problem too (but no report from you either). I am working on wrapfig now. What about `\WF@finale`?